# How to add a shortcut event in javafx with combination of Ctrl + P +X

Tags: javafx

```
table.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
  // final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.P, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
  // final KeyCombination k = new KeyCodeCombina

  public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
    if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.P && key.isControlDown()) {
      //My Code
    }
  }
});
```

I want to invoke the event with the shortcut keycombination of Ctrl+P+X

Answer (score 3):

It is actually a little hard to understand what Ctrl+P+X means.  I am going to assume it means that you press ctrl, then you press p, then you press x (potentially releasing the p before you press the x).  I'll also assume that the order matters, e.g. press ctrl, then press x then press p would not count.  Anyway a bit of speculation on my part, perhaps not exactly what you want, but hopefully you will get the gist of the provided solution and be able to adapt it to your situation.

The solution monitors both key presses and releases so that it can keep track of the state of key presses to determine if the key combination triggers.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalTime;

public class KeyCombo extends Application {

    KeyCombination ctrlP = KeyCodeCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+P");
    KeyCombination ctrlX = KeyCodeCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+X");

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label lastPressedLabel = new Label();

        TextField textField = new TextField();

        BooleanProperty pDown = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        textField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (ctrlP.match(event)) {
                pDown.set(true);
            }

            if (pDown.get() && ctrlX.match(event)) {
                pDown.set(false);
                lastPressedLabel.setText(
                        LocalTime.now().toString()
                );
            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (!event.isControlDown()) {
                pDown.set(false);
            }
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(10,
                new Label("Press Ctrl+P+X"),
                textField,
                lastPressedLabel
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If you can, I'd advise trying to use a simpler control scheme, e.g. just Ctrl+P or Ctrl+X (which is directly supported by the key code combination event matching), rather than using a composite control scheme of Ctrl+P+X.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not the thing i wanted. I am trying to press the keys together, i.e, the way we press Ctrl+Alt+del for an event. But instead of the Alt modifier i want P pressed down.

Comment: Do you want it to work also when pressed in the order P+Ctrl+X? (the same way Alt+Ctrl+Del works)

Comment: I'm sure you can tweak the solution to get exactly what you want.